# Can two connected sockets listen on different ports?

Tags: c, sockets, unix

Imagine the client has a socket that is listening on the port 80. Can this socket connect with a server socket that listens on other different port? Or must the server listen on port 80 too?

I refer network sockets of type AF_INET.

Comment: Not clear what you want to accomplish. Maybe you should read a good introductionary article about sockets first?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no requirement that the port number on two different ends of a TCP connection have to be the same.  In fact, they rarely are.

The server socket (the one that's listening) needs to be bound to a known port number (ex. 80 for HTTP) so that a client can know where to connect to.  When a client socket makes a connection to the server, an available local port number it typically chosen at random.  The client does have the option to bind to a specific port before connecting, but this is not required.

A TCP socket is defined by 4 values: local IP, local port, remote IP, remote port.  Because of this, you can have multiple client sockets (all with the same local IP but different ports) each connected to a given remote IP and port.

Comment: Thank you! That answers my question! Just one more little question, after the client pick a random port, the OS will tell the server which port was chosen right? Once again, thanks for your answer!

Comment: @DanielOliveira Yes, when the server accepts a new connection the IP and port of the client are returned in a parameter to the `accept` function.